# How to invoke Sumo from Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm new with OMNet++ and Sumo I followed the steps described in this [tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) but when I try to run the veins demo scenario at the final step I only get the OMNet++ simulation working without the Sumo one while it is supposed to be running in parallel
Any suggestion I'll be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Okay I could invoke Sumo in parallel with OMNet++ by changing the command `/c/Users/user/src/veins-4.4/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe`  to `/c/Users/user/src/veins-4.4/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c /c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo-gui.exe`

Thank you

Comment: Maybe, you want to accept this answer as the solution to mark yor question as answered. Therefore, this post can be more effective for helping people with a similar problem.